# Can you use multiple jquery selectors in WinJs?

Tags: jquery, windows-8, winjs

I'm writing a windows 8 app and I'm using jQuery.

I have the following line of code which doesn't work:

```
$('#myId1', '#myId2').hide();
```

But this works just fine.

```
$('#myId1').hide();

$('#myId2').hide();
```

Not a big deal but the first line of code should work just the same. 
Has anyone experienced this/know of a workaround ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jquery selectors are like css selectors.
If you want to select all elements with `style1` union elements with `style2` you have to use **comma** :

```
style1, style2
```

The comma mark unions two selectos. So for hiding elements `#myId1` and `#myId2` you will code:

```
$('#myId1, #myId2').hide();
```